# C++ Overloading [] for std::list containing shared_ptr

Tags: c++, list, stl, shared-ptr

I'm trying to overload the `[]` operator (similar to `std::vector::operator[]`) for a `list` containing `shared_ptr`. It needs to return a reference to an element at position `index` (design specs I've been given).

Classes `car` and `truck` are derived from abstract base class `vehicle`.
Class `dealership` contains a `std::list<std::shared_ptr<vehicle>> dealershipLot;`

This is how I've been trying to overload the `[]` operator;
`std::list<std::shared_ptr<vehicle>>& Dealership::operator[](size_t index)`

I tried using `std::find` to get an iterator to the element position and return a reference using `&(findIter)` but it seems `std::find` needs an overloaded `==` to function with my list type, but I get the error

`binary ==: no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type std::shared_ptr<vehicle> (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

The following is a shortened version of my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class vehicle {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    vehicle(){ name.clear(); }
    vehicle(string v) : name(v){};
    string getName() const { return name; };
    virtual void display(ostream&) const = 0;
};

class Car : public vehicle {
protected:
    int no;
public:
    Car(){ no = 0; };
    Car(string n, int no) : vehicle(n), no(no) {};
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    int getNo() const{ return no; }
    void display(ostream& os) const {
        os << name << " " << no << std::endl;
    }
};

class Truck : public vehicle {
protected:
    int no;
    int km;
public:
    Truck(){ no = 0; };
    Truck(string n, int no, int km) : vehicle(n), no(no), km(km) {};
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    int getNo() const{ return no; }
    int getKm() const{ return km; }
    void display(ostream& os) const {
        os << name << " " << no << "" << km << std::endl;
    }
};

class Dealership{
    string dealershipName;
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<vehicle>> dealershipLot;
public:
    Dealership(){ dealershipName.clear(); dealershipLot.clear(); };
    Dealership(const std::string n);
    Dealership(const Dealership&); //Copy constructor
    Dealership& operator=(const Dealership&); //Copy assignment operator
    Dealership(Dealership&&); //Move constructor
    Dealership&& operator=(Dealership&&); //Move assignment operator
    void operator+=(std::shared_ptr<vehicle> veh); //Operator += overload 

    bool operator==(const std::shared_ptr<vehicle> other){  //???
        return dealershipName == other->getName();
    }

    std::list<std::shared_ptr<vehicle>>& operator[](size_t index){ //???

        /*size_t index = 3;
        std::list<std::shared_ptr<vehicle>>::iterator findIter =
            std::find(dealershipLot.begin(), dealershipLot.end(), index);
        cout << &(findIter) << endl;
        return &(findIter);*/
    }
};

int main()
{
    Dealership d1("lot3");
    d1 += std::move(std::shared_ptr<vehicle>(new Car("Toyota", 15)));
    return 0;
}
```

How do I overload the `[]` operator to get a reference to the `list` element?

Comment: `std::find` is not what you want.  Try `std::next` or `std::advance`.

Comment: off topic: `operator[]` for `std::list` seems to be a popular question this week. `std::list` isn't designed for random access. Do this to pass the class, but think really hard before doing it on the job.

Comment: You want to "get reference to the list element", but your operator is returning a list...that makes no sense. If you want to return a reference to a list element, then the operator should be changed to return the correct type. Without further context, overloading the `==` operator for a dealership and a vehicle makes no sense. Finally, why not store the vehicles in std::array or std::vector rather than std::list? If you are indexing into the list, you should be using the correct data structure (array rather than a linkedlist)

Comment: Got it to work with `std::advance`. Thank you! As for using `list`, it's in the specs.

Comment: @syntaxerror recommend reverting the edit and posting your solution as an answer with a bit of explanatory padding to help out the next person with this problem. Not only may it gather rep for you, but it's the correct place to put an answer around here.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the comment. I've made the changes. As you can see I'm new to asking questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
For anyone interested I overloaded `[]` as;

```
//Operator [] return reference to element at position n
    vehicle& Task::operator[](size_t index){
        std::list<std::shared_ptr<vehicle>>::iterator it = dealershipLot.begin();
        std::advance(it, index);
        return **it;
    }
```

I created an iterator that advances through the `dealershipLot` list `index` positions.Then returned the object that the iterator is pointing to as a reference.